# How to get unique id in iOS device?

Tags: ios

I have used mac address to identify iOS devices in server side. When run my application with iOS 7 unable to retrieve the correct mac address. Alternately i used

```
NSUUID *oNSUUID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
[strApplicationUUID setString:[oNSUUID UUIDString]];
```

property. But this value also changed after every new installation of application. Now i want detect particular device in server side? How can i get some unique id per device in iOS?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can no longer get a unique ID per device. [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) is the best you're going to get. Apple has systematically disabled identifying a specific device so that users' IDs can't be passed around by marketers.

To get the identifier ID as a string, you can use

```
let deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

#### UPDATE

If you want a universal ID then you have the option to use [`advertisingIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier). However, if the user has limited ad tracking in their device settings then this value will simply return all zeroes.

```
import AdSupport

let identifierManager = ASIdentifierManager.shared()
if identifierManager.isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled {
    let deviceId = identifierManager.advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
}
```

**N.B.** Apple recommends that this code only be used by companies building advertisement frameworks, rather than the app developers themselves. If you use this within your code for non-ad-related purposes then prepare to have your app rejected.

Comment: get device id in swift by    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402327/how-to-get-unique-id-in-ios-device/32181411#32181411

Comment: In case anyone else wound up here, like I did, coming from libgdx/robovm land looking for a way to do this in Java:
UIDevice device = UIDevice.getCurrentDevice();
String id = device.getIdentifierForVendor().asString();

Answer (score 48):

The best way to get the device id is *identifierForVendor*

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

NSString  *currentDeviceId = [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
```

**UPDATE**

For Swift 4.1 use

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

Answer (score 26):

Getting device ID in

Swift 3

```
let device_id = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
```

Swift 4:

```
let device_id = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

Comment: Hi..In my application I need to get device id. Does apple supports getting device ID? And can we submit apps to appstore

Comment: Hi @hardik thanks for reply. While testing on device I came to know one thing that I am getting different UUID if I uninstall and reinstall application every time.  We can't get same id once user deletes our application.

Comment: hi @hardik is there any way to get same UDID?

Comment: @Jayesh which language is used swift or Obj- c if swift than this method is coorect                                       or else you can get                                                                                                            1)  let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString

Comment: Update for swift 3.0: `let deviceID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString`

Comment: Make sure you 'import UIKit' before your class declaration or the compiler won't know what UIDevice is

Answer (score 8):

**Getting Device Id in Swift 3.x**

```
let deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this lib: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID

Please look on the table in the Persistence section. `uuidForDevice` will cover the most of needed cases and it is the best replacement to udid from old versions of iOS.

Examples in `Readme` are in Objective-C but it works with Swift too. I have used it since Swift first release until now (Swift 4.1).

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5

```
let deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use UIDevice's `identifierForVendor` method like so:

```
let deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

But as explained here in great detail: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor
the ID changes on every reinstall of the app (from AppStore).

One easy solution to circumvent this is to use the Keychain to store the deviceId once acquired. If the keychain item is not present - which will be the case for the first install* - acquire the deviceId as stated above and store it in the keychain.

*) This is iOS so there has to be some gotchas: If the device is reset or restored from backup, keychain items might disappear. So there's no 100% chance here, but since this scenario is quite unlikely, it's the best choice you've got.