# IOS, How apps are able to get device unique ID?

Tags: ios, iphone

I was reading this: [How to get unique id in iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402327/how-to-get-unique-id-in-ios-device) and was interested to know how IOS devices can be tracked?

For example, I was once banned on platform X and I did the following:

Deleted the app (and all other apps from same developer)
Changed IP
removed the SIM card
Turned off tracking in IOS settings
Did a restart

But when I tried to sign up using a completely different Gmail I did see the ban message immediately, so how was platform X able to detect me?

It's worth noting that if I delete a complete system reset (which changes device ID) I was able to create a new account, but if I do system reset then restore from backup I was banned again.

From what I know in IOS an app can't access the UDID anymore on IOS 17 and earlier.

Comment: "*how was Grindr able to detect me?*" Nobody here will be able to answer this question. Since the actual answer is likely proprietary, those with the information necessary to formulate a complete & helpful answer to this specific question are almost undoubtedly legally bound not to reveal it. Aside, but ban evasion is ethically dubious (at best) and may be illegal dependent on your jurisdiction.

Comment: @esqew Hi, I don't want to unban my account as I said I could just do system reset, I'm concerned about which piece of data Grindr has access to, as per what I read able doesn't disclose UDID anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Grindr user ID was stored in the keychain. Keychain entries survive app deletion and system resets.

This is an undocumented feature but apparently so many apps rely on this that when Apple changed this in one of the iOS 11 betas (iirc) they immediately reverted to the old behaviour.

Comment: But when I do system reset then login using same apple ID to icloud doesn't this restore the keychain? plus how can I access keychain in IOS and delete that value Grindr stored?

Comment: No, the keychain item was probably just stored in the device, not in iCloud.  The only way you can remove the element (aside from perhaps jailbreaking) is to erase the device. If Grindr used the device check framework to ban your device then there is no way to remove the ban.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok that makes sense, though apple should allow erasing the keychain from device for added security... Any way you said "If Grindr used the device check framework to ban your device then there is no way to remove the ban" I don't agree as system reset will always work (apple doesn't allow tracking devices)

Comment: No, you can't clear device check - it allows an app to register two bits of information about a device. It doesn't identify the device to the app developer - the app can simply say "store these two bits of data for my app on this device" and "what are the values (on/off) of the two bits for my app on this device?"  The data is stored on Apple's servers, so it is effective across device erase

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_per-device_data